# Imposing restrictions on latent class

Tags: r, stata, logistic-regression, categorical-data

I am doing latent class analysis in R (poLCA), now I have one question in my assignment where I have to impose some restrictions on my latent class model e.g.

p_{11}^B|X=p_{11}^C|X

or

p_{11}^{A|X}=1

where X is the latent class and A,B,C are independents. I tried to mess with the starting values (`probs.start`), but that did not help.

```
somemodel <- poLCA(cbind(A, B, C, D) ~ 1, df1_expanded, nclass = 2)
```

Any ideas?

Update:
Does a solution to this question exist in other script based programs (e.g. Stata) with good (latex-)table output options?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is currently no such functionality in poLCA. However, one could use LEM for such analyses, which is freely available.

Comment: I had to do this for a course assignment. The course was mainly on LEM. While I managed to use R in the whole exam. This was the only aspect I could not replicate from LEM. The issue with LEM is that the output und script options are very poor. Consequently I use R's Textconnection command to import my LEM results into R and make nice tables from them.

Comment: Still a good point, maybe there are other script based programs who can do this.